# Refreshing UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an IBAction that displays what is being pressed on certain buttons to a UILabel. I have another IBAction for equalPressed button that does many things, but I also added titleDisplay.text = nil; It works perfectly the first time. Then after I press the equalPressed button it doesn't show up. I know it is because i have titleDisplay.text set to nil. However, I don't know how to clear the UILabel with the equalPressed button so my other buttons can be displayed on the screen without appending constantly

First IBAction

```
- (IBAction) titleLabel: (UIButton *) sender {
    NSString *titleOfButton = [[sender titleLabel] text]; 
    titleDisplay.text = [[titleDisplay text] stringByAppendingString: titleOfButton]; 
}
```

Second IBAction

```
- (IBAction) equalPressed: (UIButton *) sender {
    titleDisplay.text = nil; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this would work *only* the first time is because when you assign `nil` to an object, you're essentially dumping your reference to it. You should instead set the text to an empty string, like so:

```
[titleDisplay setText:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally overlooked the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
- (IBAction) equalPressed: (UIButton *) sender {
    titleDisplay.text = @""; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I really feel idiotic, I just kept overlooking the obvious. Seriously thanks again.